# Excel to Generate formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have 600+ worksheets in my XLS document. I need to generate a formula in the first worksheet.

```
=HYPERLINK("#1!A1", CONCATENATE("YES (", COUNTA('1'!B:B)-1, ")"))
...
=HYPERLINK("#9!A1", CONCATENATE("YES (", COUNTA('9'!B:B)-1, ")"))
=HYPERLINK("#10!A1", CONCATENATE("YES (", COUNTA('10'!B:B)-1, ")"))
=HYPERLINK("#11!A1", CONCATENATE("YES (", COUNTA('11'!B:B)-1, ")"))
```

As you can see the formula only differs by the name of the worksheet (it's numerical 1... 624)

When I copy and paste the formula' I get the same exact formula.

Can anyone help me with this? I don't mind using VBA to store the formula in Sheet1 starting in Cell E5 to E624

Comment: `Range(...).Formula = "formula here"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA a simple loop will do:

```
Sub createHyperLink()
    For i = 1 To 624
        Range("E" & i).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#" & i & "!A1"", CONCATENATE(""YES ("", COUNTA('" & i & "'!B:B)-1, "")""))"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @softwareisfun either. I personally use modules but it's up to you

Comment: @softwareisfun unqualified `Range` call will work against `ActiveSheet` if that's in a module, and if it's in a worksheet's code-behind the same code will work against *that worksheet* (i.e. `Me`/`Sheet1`), so "either" is a tad short and bug-prone. Best always qualify `Range` calls with a proper `Worksheet` object instance when you mean it to work against a specific `Worksheet` object instance. Otherwise you'll inevitably run into problems.